# How to make a button change color when clicked and then change back to its original color when a different button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two buttons and I want the background-color to change color when I click one of them and then change back to its original color when I click the other button. I also want a hover feature that shows the color the button would be if it were to be clicked with some opacity.

I've tried

```
button:hover{
   background-color: pink;
   opacity: .5;
}

button:focus{
   background-color: pink;
}
```

This works fine until I click anywhere in the screen and the color change is gone.

I've also tried

```
var buttons = $('button');
buttons.click(function() {
  buttons.css('background-color', 'snow');
  $(this).css('background-color', 'pink');
});
```

This also works fine except the hover effect stops working like I want it to. When I hover over a button, you can see the opacity change but it is no longer pink.

Is there a way to adjust either of these attempts to make it work properly? Thanks in advance

Comment: use class to change colors, addClass and removeClass toggle.

Comment: I would just recommend using the focus pseudo selector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your code is overriding the `background-color` property. Add the `!important` to your `.button:hover` and it will work as you expect. Snippet below:

```js
var buttons = $('button');
buttons.click(function() {
  buttons.css('background-color', 'snow');
  $(this).css('background-color', 'pink');
});
```

```css
button:hover {
  background-color: pink !important;
  opacity: .5;
}

button:focus {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>First</button>
<button>Second</button>
<button>Third</button>
```

Comment: This is **not** the best way to solve this. Just reorder the selectors lmao.

Comment: @Kognise, can't figure out why. Reorder the selectors didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

As i said use Radio Buttons...
[edit]
  with 2 version to get value event  JS or jQuery

```js
/* jQuery */

  $('input[name="btGrp"]').on('change', function() {
    console.clear();
    console.log ('button is ',  $(this).val());

    // do button stuff...
  });
/* */

/* pure JS * /

  document.querySelectorAll('input[name="btGrp"]').forEach(xRadio=>{xRadio.onchange=evt=>{
    console.clear();
    console.log( 'button is ', evt.target.value);

    // do button stuff...
  }});
/* */
```

```css
input[type="radio"]        { display: none } 
input[type="radio"]+label  {
    display           : inline-block;
    background-color  : snow;
    border            : 3px solid #7986cb;
    border-radius     : 6px;
    color             : #37474f;;
    width             : 160px;
    padding           : 5px 0;
    text-align        : center;
    margin            : 5px;
}
input[type="radio"]+label:hover            { background-color: lightblue; }

input[type="radio"]:checked + label        { background-color: pink;      }
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:hover  { background-color: lightgreen }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input  id="bt-1" type="radio" name="btGrp" value="b1" >
<label for="bt-1">button 1 </label>
<input  id="bt-2" type="radio" name="btGrp" value="b2" >
<label for="bt-2">button 2 </label>
<input  id="bt-3" type="radio" name="btGrp" value="b3" >
<label for="bt-3">button 3 </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You just need to add foucus pseudo class to button whenever button is focused the color remains and if anywhere you click the button will loose it's color**

```
.my-button:{
background-color:black;
}

.my-button:focus{
background-color:white;
}
```